# Hitting escape to continue does not work in Suggested Edit Dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: Hit esc to continue]

As you can see from this image, there is a message:

> This suggestion still needs 2 approve votes from other reviewers. Close this popup (**or hit Esc**) to continue.

Emphasis is obviously mine.

However no matter how many times I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it didn't close. I made sure that the modal had priority. I dragged it a round a little and hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> a few more times to make sure, but it just sat there. I then had to click the 'X' to close it.

Not a massive problem, but either the text should be removed or the bug should be fixed.

Hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> only won't work on this type of model. @FrédéricHamidi has tested and found out that it still works in the `Close Vote` popup.

Comment: I can repro this, but it is specific to the suggested edit review popup (hitting `ESC` works as expected in the close vote popup, for instance).

Comment: Thank you @FrédéricHamidi I'll update it.

Comment: Updated the title to make it clear what the bug is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix is rolling out with build `2015.1.30.3034` on meta and `2015.1.30.2257` on sites.

All it took was the removal of the `.no-esc-remove` class from the popup's lightbox - which actually only started to behave correctly after the batch of fixes concerning the stacking of popups we can have due to the markdown editor & rejection reason popup inside the suggested edit popup. That class turned out to be just a dirty hack, introduced to prevent the whole stack of popups to close when esc is pressed.